# Jetpack Compose: Not able to show text in TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Recently I'm playing with Jetpack Compose and I noticed that the text may not show up in TextField.

So I have a `ViewModel` with `Flow` of `ViewState`.

In my `Compose` file, I have something similar to this:

```
@Composable
internal fun TestScreen() {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
    TestScreen {
        viewState = state,
        actioner = { ... }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TestScreen(viewState: ViewState, actioner: () -> Unit) {
    var name by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(viewState.name)
        )
    }
    Surface {
        ....
        Column {
            ....

            OutlinedTextField(
                ...
                value = name,
                onValueChange = { textFieldValue -> 
                    name = textFieldValue
                    actioner(...)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

the `OutlineTextField` will never show what's already inside `viewState.name`

However, if I change this:

```
    var name by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(viewState.name)
        )
    }
```

To this:

```
    var name = TextFieldValue(viewState.name)
```

Obviously it could show the value in `viewState.name`.

According to the Documentation (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) in which it recommends using `remember` & `mutableStateOf` to handle the changes.

I'll be very grateful if someone could help me to explain why the code with `remember` doesn't work but the directly assigned value worked?

## EDIT

`viewState.name` is a `String`

and I "partially solved" this issue by doing the following:

```
    var name by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue("")
        )
    }
    
    name = TextFieldValue(viewState.name)
```

then the name can be shown. But it doesn't look quite right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remember` is used just to ensure that upon recomposition, the value of the `mutableStateOf` object does not get re-initialised to the initial value.

For example,

```
@Composable
fun Test1(){
 var text by mutableStateOf ("Prev Text")
 Text(text)
  Button(onClick = { text = "Updated Text" }){
      Text("Update The Text")
  }
}
```

would not update the text on button click. This is because button click will change the mutableStateOf `text`, which will trigger a recomposition. However, when the control reaches the first line of the Composable, it will re-initialise the variable `text` to "Prev Text".

This is where `remember` comes in.

If you change the initialisation above to

`var text by remember { mutableStateOf ("Prev Text") }`,

It wil tell compose to track this variable, and "remember" its value, and use it again on recomposition, when the control reaches the initialisation logic again. Hence, remember over there acts as a "guard" that does not let the control reach into the initialisation logic, and returns that latest remembered value of the variable it currently has in store.

Comment: Anything else you wanted to ask?

Comment: Yes. So `remember` really meant to remember the state, and it will keep the initial value even it changes elsewhere, right?

Comment: It seems that the docs are saying otherwise? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?authuser=1#state-in-composables it says if using `remember` with `mutableState`, when there are any changes to the `mutableState`'s value, it will trigger a recomposition. In my case, `viewState.name` will be different from the initial value, why is it not showing up?

Comment: Hey also, the mutableStateOf cannot be used with any value. Only certain types are supported. TextFieldValue is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. May I ask if you have any detailed doc stating which types are supported by `mutableStateOf`?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I know that all the primitive types are supported, and I kinda think that that's all that is. Also, ```listOf(...)```, the immutable list, is supported

Comment: Thanks. It's kinda weird though. The source code of `mutableStateOf` only mentioned a generic type `T` and set an observer on it. I hope this is a bug for only subscribing changes in a limited types ‍♂️

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, or they would not have documented it in a how-to doc. Also, I have tested this before. Other than the supported types, no other objects when used as mutableState trigger recompositions.

Comment: That's very thoughtful. For sure missing documents for this behaviour is a bit annoying

Comment: Hmm it kinda is