# How to initialize a remember value from an asynchronously provided argument?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I want to initialize a `remember`ed `StateMap` from a `List` argument I'm getting passed to my Composable. After the initialization, I want to modify this list and remember the changes on recomposition (hence the `remember`). The problem is that this `List` is loaded from a Room database asynchronously, and on first composition, it's empty.
The `expandedStates` `Map` never gets filled with values so I assume on recomposition the initialization block is not executed again.

How do I initialize this StateMap correctly?

```
@Composable
fun TodoList(
    todos: List<Todo>,
    [...]
) {
    // this map stays empty
    val expandedStates = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Long, Boolean>().apply {
            todos.map { todo ->
                todo.id to false
            }.toMap().also {
                putAll(it)
            }
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue of the not existing key in map is as you say.
Thus you need to tell the remember that the todos is a key that requires an update.
If you do not want to lose part of the state of a remember you can open a second one.

In the code below, I first create the map and put a remember around to keep the state. Secondly, I create a remember that refreshes every time todos refreshes.
There I merge the two maps and associate the existing value or false as a default.

```kotlin
/* Jetpack Compose Desktop but still applies to Android */

data class TODOItem(val id: Long, val content: String)

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun TODOList(todos: List<TODOItem>) {
    val expandedStates = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Long, Boolean>() }
    remember(todos) {
        if (expandedStates.isNotEmpty()) {
            val updated = todos.map { todo -> todo.id }
            val mergeMap = (expandedStates.keys + updated).associateWith{ expandedStates[it] ?: false }
            expandedStates.clear()
            expandedStates.putAll(mergeMap)
        } else {
            expandedStates.putAll(todos.associate { todo -> todo.id to false })
        }
    }
    LazyColumn {
        items(todos) { todo ->
            Card(
                onClick = {
                    expandedStates[todo.id] = expandedStates[todo.id]?.not() ?: true
                }
            ) {
                Column {
                    Text(text = "id ${todo.id}")
                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = expandedStates[todo.id]!!
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "content ${todo.content}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
fun main() {
    Window {
        val todos = remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<TODOItem>()) }
        var items = 0
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            fixedRateTimer(period = 2000L) {
                todos.value = if (todos.value.isEmpty()) {
                    items += 20
                    List(items) { TODOItem(it.toLong(), "content $it") }
                } else emptyList()
            }
        }
        TODOList(
            todos = todos.value
        )
    }
}
```

**Note: If you have a query that deletes items in the database the ids are still present in the UI.**

If your problem only requires you to update once after an empty list you can pass the remember from your code a key to update on.

```kotlin
val expandedStates = remember(todos) {
    mutableStateMapOf(*todos.map { todo -> todo.id to false }.toTypedArray())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the call to remeber. Also, I assume that the passed in parameter `todos` is also a state-holder, which will trigger recompositions. Read the docs about remember to learn more.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411467/15880865, for more info

Comment: If I remove remember I lose all `expandedStates` everytime something in the todos `List` changes.

Comment: Well, is that not the idea? To update the state based on the current value of `todos`

Comment: No. Sorry if I didn't make this clear enough. I updated my question. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm sorry it's still not clear. What do you mean `remember` "the changes" on recompositions?

Comment: I don't want to lose the state of the `expandedStates` map.

Comment: You really should read this answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411467/15880865

Comment: The question might be irrelevant to you, but the answer explains it well. You cannot both use `remember` and call the initialisation block wrapped inside it. The whole point of `remember` is to prevent re-initialising the variable (state) on every recompostion and return the in-memory value of the variable.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Btw, I am not who voted you down!

Comment: Oh I didn't comment because of that. It's ok.